# How can I get the prompt of "Would you like to install this device software?" in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, security

When I installed a software, during the installation, Windows security prompted "Would you like to install this device software?" I choose "Always trust software from XXX" and I didn't get the prompt any more when I install the software.

But now I want to withdraw my decision, and I'd like to get the prompt when I install the software. What should I do to enable the Windows security's prompt? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to go into the certificate manager and remove the certificate you approved.

1. Click Start | Run (or Windows + R)
2. Type 'certmgr.msc' - without the quotes

You should then be able to find the certificate from the vendor in 'Trusted Publishers' | 'Certificates'

3. Select the certificate and press DELETE

(For safety, I would recommend you right click the certificate and choose 'All Tasks' | Export. At least this way, you have a backup copy should you need it)